# Using jQuery, how do you select another element based on the clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Difficult to phrase this as a question in one small title.

Basically, I have a div:

```
<div class="sites" id="site1"></div>
```

which is clickable by the user, and when that div is clicked, I want another div to appear with a similar ID:

```
<div id="site1_desc" class="description_holder">
```

Is there a way that when the former div is clicked, I can have the latter selected for use. I have the same div combo for site2, 3, 4 etc. I was thinking something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sites).click(function(){
      $(this&'_desc').css({visibility: "visible"});
     });
});
```

I understand that the above wont work, but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sites').click(function(){
   $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'_desc').css({visibility: "visible"});
 });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teaR5/)**

Comment: Also missing a quote in the selector

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this.id instead of this to get the id. Concatenate this event source object id with the string "_desc". You also need to use `#` for id selector at the beginning of selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sites').click(function(){
      $("#" + this.id + '_desc').css({visibility: "visible"});
     });
});
```

Comment: Missing a quote in the selector

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.id` to get the id of clicked item , Also you are missing a quote in the selector and need to put `#` before id selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.sites').click(function(){
   //.......^..................
      $('#'+this.id+'_desc').css({visibility: "visible"});
     //....^....^..........
     });
});
```

`+` can be used for concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Specify the target in a data-attribute on the clicked element:

```
<div class="sites" id="site1" data-target='site1_desc'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-target]').on('click', function(){
        $('[data-target=' + $(this).data('target') + ']').show();
    }
});
```

...then it would apply to any element that has a `data-target`. This pattern is used in a lot of popular front-end frameworks; for example, Twitter Bootstrap's collapsable menus.